# Parallel computing in python significantly slower than regular for loop

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, scipy

So I'm trying to do some simple image analysis in python, I have a numpy array of the video in question and it has  a shape of (930, 256, 256), i.e. 930 frames of a resolution of 256 by 256 pixels.

I'm trying to do seed pixel correlation in parallel, my computer has 12 cores, so I should be able to write a parallel for loop and get my results faster.

This is what I came up with after looking around for ways to write parallel for loops. However, it's significantly slower than the non parallel version!!

Perhaps someone can tell me a better way of writing it? (using other libraries!) 
Or maybe someone can tell me why it is slower?

Here's the code I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
from joblib import Parallel, delayed  
import multiprocessing

def corr(pixel, seed_pixel):
    return pearsonr(pixel, seed_pixel)[0]

def get_correlation_map(seed_x, seed_y, frames):
    seed_pixel = np.asarray(frames[:, seed_x, seed_y], dtype=np.float32)

    # Reshape into time and space
    frames = np.reshape(frames, (total_number_of_frames, width*height))
    #correlation_map = []
    #####################################
    print 'Getting correlation...'

    # The parallel version.
    correlation_map = Parallel(n_jobs=12)(delayed(corr)(pixel, seed_pixel) for pixel in frames.T)

    # Non parallel version
    #correlation_map = []
    #for i in range(frames.shape[-1]):
        #correlation_map.append(pearsonr(frames[:, i], seed_pixel)[0])
    #####################################
    correlation_map = np.asarray(correlation_map, dtype=np.float32)
    correlation_map = np.reshape(correlation_map, (width, height))
    print np.shape(correlation_map)

    return correlation_map
```

All I need is a way to parallelize a for loop that will append its results  to a list in the order of the iteration. So I suppose synchronization could be an issue!

Comment: Have you looked at your CPU utilization to try to find if the problem is IO bound in some way? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu! And strangely the CPUs aren't taxed at 100, neither of them. They say around the 50s. So problem could very well be IO... Any other suggestions?

Comment: The CPU's not being taxed is exactly what you are looking for. If you are using ubuntu and don't already have `mpstat` install `sudo apt-get sysstat`. Look closely at the iowait column.

Comment: IO wait column stayed %0.28 the whole way through a test run...

Answer (score 1):

You are likely having an issue because the arguments passed to `Parallel` are large and all being serialized. You can use `backend="threading"` to avoid this if (as i assume) `personr` releases the GIL. Otherwise you might have to look into `numpy.memmap` and stick with using `multiprocessor`

```
correlation_map = Parallel(n_jobs=12, backend="threading")(delayed(corr)(pixel, seed_pixel) for pixel in frames.T)
```

Comment: if pearsonr doesn't release the GIL, would that be causing the slowness?
I tried what you suggested, but it's still slower than single core task :(

Comment: Yes, it could be IO bound. or in Amdahl's law (B ~ 1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law having to share an IO resource.